# make Marker's Title Clickable

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-markers

In Google Map V2, We make Marker Clickable by:

```
         mGoogleMap.setOnMarkerClickListener(MainActivity.this);
```

and add title by:

```
      markerOptions.title(name + " : " + vicinity );
```

But How can we make Title Clickable? i.e something like onTitleClickListener.

Comment: Is your title TextView?

Answer (score 0):

you can set a listener for markers.

```
mGoogleMap.setOnMarkerClickListener(this);
```

then implement listener's functions;

```
@Override
    public boolean onMarkerClick(Marker marker) {
// blabla    
return false;
}     

@Override
    public void onInfoWindowClick(Marker marker) {
// find which marker clicked from its id    
}
```